Report Builder Subscription Date Range Parameter and Client Name Parameter Via SQL Table
How I have Report Builder. Which has a parameter of
Start Date and End Date and Customer Client.
I want to have a subscription that every month 1st it would save a word file of the data of the previous month / quarter depending on the customer.
The goal is to have a monthly / quarterly report. Depending on the customer name.
For Example
Customer                   Frequency
A                           Monthly   (Jan 2024) [Date Range]
B                           Quarterly (Jan 2024- Mar2024) [Date Range]
I havent done anything yet

Use a Data-Driven Subscription or schecule a Powershell (or similar) script that generates the reports using URL Access.
